# Can you save variables in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: variables, visual-studio-code, workspace

I am trying to teach myself code/automate some tasks in my downtime at work, and the IDE that IT installed for me use python with is VSCode, which I don't seem to understand fully.

My only formal education in coding was using matlab. I remember being able to define a variable or function in my code, run it, and then call the very same variable/function in the terminal, which would return what I had defined. There was also a workspace directory that showed all the variables I had stored. However, is VSCode, i cannot find anything like that - I even had to install a separate package to RUN my code. Is it possible to have VSCode do what I described above in matlab? It was a long process getting IT to install VSC so I really do not want to try to get a new interpreter unless I absolutely have to. If there is some significant difference in matlab and VSC that I am not grasping, I would appreciate if that could be explained because I feel very much in over my head right now.

```
testVar = 8
```

I would expect to be able to type `testVar` into the terminal, and have it return `8`, but instead:

```
testVar : The term 'testVar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ testVar
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (testVar:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is REPL. You used a REPL in matlab. If you search for that, you may find answers.

Comment: on the command line/terminal type `python` or `python3` and you get the REPL for Python

Answer (score 0):

As rioV8 mentioned in the comments to the OP's post, if you enter `python` in the terminal, you get the python REPL which is like the command window in Matlab. You could then try commands to display the list of variables (which I don't recall at the top of my head), but I don't think you can get the visual display like Matlab's workspace.

For that, one option is to set a breakpoint at the end of your code, and run the code in debug mode (F5 on Windows). Then you can see the variable workspace as well as play around with the values using the debug console (which acts like a command window during debugging).

However, for more frequent interactions between the code, workspace, and command window, I recommend using jupyter notebook instead. There you can run code and view the variable workspace (search `variable` in the command palette (ctrl + alt + P)) in the variable explorer. Hopefully your python setup includes that option; you can try creating a new file in VSCode with .ipynb extension.